# Sitecore 9 Installation, CPU now at 100% usage

Tags: configuration

I've installed Solr & Sitecore 9 using the following tutorials/scripts and now my CPU usage is at 100 percent, stemming mostly from Java and XConnectSearchIndexer as per the screenshot. Has anybody got any information on what might be the issue here? A colleague of mine also followed the same installation procedure and is facing the same issue.

Tutorials/Scripts used:

- https://medium.com/redhotminute-australia/setting-up-solr-with-ssl-for-sitecore-9-acdf009edd93
- https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/installing-sitecore-9-installing-the-platform

[image: Image of my Task Manager]

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: What solr version are you using

Comment: Try clearing cache, if this is not related to Solr. 

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/java-platform-se-binary-consuming-almost-80-of-cpu 

Which JRE and Solr version you are using? Clear cache with this.

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I am using Solr 6.6.2

Comment: @SitecoreSam I am using Solr 6.6.2 and JRE 1.8.0_191

I tried clearing the java cache, but no luck.

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried this with JRE 9.0.1 and the issue still persists.. (Though it does seem slightly better, it's hovering around 85-90 now)

Comment: Do you see requests in the Solr logfile? is it related to Sitecore sending commands (which?) or just Solr going on its own (I would not suspect the later - have never seen that)

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried this now with Solr 7.2.1 and the issue still persists

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of Sitecore 9 and/or failed Sitecore 9 installations? Sitecore 9 installs multiple services per installation which are all set to run by default and which collectively consume a significant amount of resources, many of which are logged under the Java task. Check all of your running Sitecore services and make sure to disable Sitecore services not required for your current running instance. Please note that unless you modify the startup mode, the services will also get restarted upon machine reboot.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I actually discovered the cause of this issue - interestingly it only occured AFTER I attached solr to nssm... Which is very strange, running it manually through cmd would allow it to work absolutely fine. But thank you for the information, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, this "bug" was only occurring once I'd used NSSM to create the service, if I install SOLR and start it manually, it works without any problems, so that's what I've resorted to doing in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this tutorial:
http://www.jondjones.com/learn-sitecore-cms/sitecore-developers-guide/sitecore-getting-with-sitecore-development/how-to-install-solr-for-sitecore no issues with this.

For Sitecore 9.0.2 I used this configuration of Instal-Solr.ps1:

```
Param(
    $solrVersion = "6.6.5",
    $installFolder = "d:\solr",
    $solrPort = "8983",
    $solrHost = "solr.lh",
    $solrSSL = $true,
    $nssmVersion = "2.24",
    $JREVersion = "1.8.0_191"
)
```